# SpannableStringBuilder not display image span for every data from Firebase (Kotlin)

Tags: java, android, kotlin, stringbuilder, spannablestring

I retrieve the data from `FireBase` and trying to display an image next to each data (`TextView`). But the image is displayed on the first data only.

**This is the output:**

[image]

I want every data to have an image.

**Here is my code:**

```
val database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().reference

val getData = object : ValueEventListener {
     override fun onDataChange(snapshot: DataSnapshot) {
     
          val myData = SpannableStringBuilder()

          for (i in snapshot.children) {
               val data = i.child("myData").value

               myData.append("$data\n\n")
               
               // Get image from drawable and set size
               val drawable: Drawable? = context?.let { ContextCompat.getDrawable(it, R.drawable.myImage) }
               drawable?.setBounds(0, 0, textView.lineHeight, textView.lineHeight)
               
               // Set image span to the first letter
               val span: ImageSpan? = drawable?.let { ImageSpan(it, ImageSpan.ALIGN_BASELINE) }
               myData.setSpan(span, 0, 1, Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE)
          }

          textView.text = myData
     }

     override fun onCancelled(error: DatabaseError) {

     }
}

database.addValueEventListener(getData)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is at `myData.setSpan(span, 0, 1, Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE)`.
You always set the image span at the first of the whole string. Do something like this:

```
override fun onDataChange(snapshot: DataSnapshot) {

    val builder = SpannableStringBuilder()

    snapshot.children.forEach { data ->
        builder.append("$data#") // the `#` doesn't mind and will be replaced with the image span

        val span = context?.let {
            ImageSpan(it, R.drawable.myImage, DynamicDrawableSpan.ALIGN_BASELINE)
        }

        builder.setSpan(
            span,
            builder.length - 1,
            builder.length,
            Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE
        )

        builder.append("\n\n") // at the end, append new lines
    }
    
    textView.text = builder
}
```

Comment: It worked, each data has an image. But had to do `myData.length - 3, myData.length - 2 ` and I don't know why.

Another problem is that the picture needs to replace the last letter. How can I put it next to the last letter?

@aminography

Comment: You mean that you want to append the picture at the end of each line?

Comment: Yes, because I don't find other way to append image next to each data.

Comment: I've changed it to fit your requirement. Please try it out.

Comment: Perfect! it worked very well and met the requirement. My first question on this site got a very accurate and fast response. Thanks!

Comment: How about I want to put an image before the first letter of the String?
I did like `builder.length - builder.length, builder.length - builder.length + 1`, but it only shows image on the first line.

Comment: it could be like this: https://hastebin.com/yameyuduqe.cs

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: Hye, can you help me solve this? Just like this case, but chronometer on each line, link is here : [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63904767/stringbuilder-to-append-chronometer-did-not-work-kotlin)

Comment: Hye, can you solve my problem in this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64175419/orderbychild-if-same-value-how-to-order-by-second-variable/64175818#64175818). @aminography