# StringBuilder to append chronometer did not work (Kotlin)

Tags: java, android, kotlin, stringbuilder, chronometer

I'm trying to put a chronometer on each line, but it didn't work.

**My output :**

[image]

**What I want :**

[image]

```
val chrono = StringBuilder()  // Is there a ChronometerBuilder?

for (i in 0 until 4){
      chronoView.base = SystemClock.elapsedRealtime()
      chronoView.start()
      chrono.append(chronoView.base)   // I don't know what to include in the parameter

      chrono.append("\n\n")
}

chronoView.text = chrono
```

Comment: I don't understand what's you expected result. Please describe more about it.

Comment: @aminography If I use normal chronometer, it only shows 1 chronometer. But I want a chronometer on multiple lines and all started at once.

Answer (score 0):

When you want to Build a String from `StringBuilder` object you need to call `.toString()` method.

So, you need to call `chrono.toString()` to get the String result.

Comment: I tried `chronoView.text = chrono.toString()` but it only shows on the first line.

Comment: Check your layout so chronoView is able to show more than one line.

Comment: @AmeerulAmeen which Java version are you using?

Comment: @AmeerulAmeen make sure that FOR loop is executed properly by       System.out.println(i);

Comment: @MikheilZhghenti I've done the normal StringBuilder like `chrono.append("Hello")` and it worked, `Hello` on each line. But in this case, I don't know what to put in the `chrono.append(??)`.

Answer (score 0):

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Chronometer is a kind of TextView.
Chronometer writes every seconds if you starts it (Chronometer has a timer itself, and displays with default format mm:ss).
So, if you want to write a text, you must stop it

If you want to show 4 clocks in your activity, use 4 Chronometer.

If you want to show 4 text in your activity, use another TextView

Comment: But I don't have the exact number of Chronometer. It depends on how much data is in Firebase, and can increase over time.

Comment: then u need to addView() dynamically