# orderByChild() if same value, how to order by second variable?

Tags: java, android, firebase, kotlin, firebase-realtime-database

I work with a list sorted by age. When there are same age, I want it to be sorted by name alphabetically.

[image]

In this case, Adam should be above and Ramsay should be below.

I don't know how to work with orderByChild() for the second variable.

```
val database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Classmate").child("student").orderByChild("age")

// orderByChild("name") // for second order
```

Comment: If there is no option to sort the items by multiple fields, you can do this using kotlin collection's sort feature after the result is delivered. `list.sortedWith(compareBy({ it.age }, { it.name }))`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When using just .orderBy("atribute") you can chain multiple ones to order the results inside the last order. For example: .orderBy("age").orderBy("name")

```
val database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Classmate").child("student").orderByChild("age").orderBy("name")
```

I haven't used it with orderByChild() but i guess it would work the same way.

Comment: There is no orderBy() function in the Android Studio query. I tried `orderByChild("age").orderByChild("name")`, the app crashed.